# Why does the point crash when free it?

Tags: c, heap-memory, mergesort, heap-corruption

In the following code, the result is ok, but the code will be crash when executing finish, and increase one error: Heap corruption detected, the free list is damaged at 0x600000008f50

```c
int *mergeSort(int *a,int count) {

    int leftCount  = count / 2;
    int rightCount = count - leftCount;
    int *leftData  = getData(a, 0, leftCount);
    int *rightData = getData(a, leftCount, count);

    int *sortedLeftData  = mergeSort(leftData, leftCount);
    int *sortedRightData = mergeSort(rightData, rightCount);

    int *resultData = mergeData(sortedLeftData, sortedRightData, leftCount,
                                rightCount);

    return resultData;
}

int *getData(int *a,int from, int to) {

    if (from > to) { return nil; }
    int *res = malloc(to - from + 1);
    for (int index = from; index < to; index ++) {

        int value = a[index];
        res[index-from] = value;
    }
    return res;
}

int *mergeData(int *a, int *b, int acount, int bcount) {

    int *result = malloc(acount + bcount);

    int aindex,bindex,rindex;
    aindex = bindex = rindex = 0;

    while (aindex < acount | bindex < bcount) {

        int value,avalue = INT_MAX,bvalue = INT_MAX;
        if (aindex < acount) { avalue = a[aindex]; }
        if (bindex < bcount) { bvalue = b[bindex]; }
        // get value from a point.
        if (avalue <= bvalue) {

            value = avalue;
            aindex ++;
        }else {
            // get value from b point.
            value = bvalue;
            bindex ++;
        }

        result[rindex] = value;
        rindex ++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I don't understand why does crash when free the point, any answer will helpfull, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your allocations are too small, and thus you are overflowing your buffers.

The `malloc` function allocates the requested number of *bytes*.  You need to multiply the number of elements you require by `sizeof(int)` if your elements are `int` type.  *e.g.*

```
int *result = malloc((acount + bcount) * sizeof(int));
```

Other potential problems I spotted while reading your code are:

1. Using the bitwise-or operator instead of logical-or:

   ```
   while (aindex < acount | bindex < bcount)
                       // ^ should be ||
   ```
2. You never free your temporary buffers, thus your program will blow out memory by leaking like crazy.  You must free `leftData`, `rightData`, `sortedLeftData` and `sortedRightData` in the `mergeSort` function after you are finished with them.

   Note that merge sort actually does not require so much allocation.  Doing so will have a huge impact on performance.  An efficient implementation only requires a single additional buffer for scratch operations, which can be allocated at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you respond to this question as so detail, and it resolved my problem.

And I will think about how to use one single buffer to implementation merge sort,

thank you very much.

Comment: I'd implementation the merge sort use one buffer as following code.

Answer (score 0):

I did implementation merge sort use single buffer, as the following code:

```c
void mergeSort(int *a, int count) {

    int *tempBuffer = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    mergeSortWithBuffer(a, 0, 0, count - 1,tempBuffer);
    free(tempBuffer);
}
void mergeSortWithBuffer(int *a, int leftStart, int rightStart, int end, int *tempBuffer) {

    int leftCount  = rightStart - leftStart;
    int rightCount = end - rightStart + 1;
    if (leftCount + rightCount <= 1) { return; }

    if (leftCount != 0) {

        // left dichotomy
        int lls = leftStart;
        int lrs = leftStart + leftCount/2;
        int lnd = rightStart - 1;
        mergeSortWithBuffer(a, lls, lrs, lnd,tempBuffer);
    }

    if (rightCount != 0) {

        // right dichotomy
        int rls = rightStart;
        int rrs = rightStart + rightCount/2;
        int rnd = end;
        mergeSortWithBuffer(a, rls, rrs, rnd,tempBuffer);
    }

    mergeData(a, leftStart, rightStart, end, tempBuffer);
}

void mergeData(int *a, int leftStart, int rightStart, int end,int *tempBuffer) {

    int leftCount  = rightStart - leftStart;
    int rightCount = end - rightStart + 1;

    int lindex,rindex;
    lindex = rindex = 0;

    while (lindex < leftCount || rindex < rightCount) {

        int lv = INT_MAX,rv = INT_MAX;
        if (lindex < leftCount) { lv = a[leftStart + lindex]; }
        if (rindex < rightCount) { rv = a[rightStart + rindex]; }

        if (lv <= rv) {

            tempBuffer[leftStart + lindex + rindex] = lv;
            lindex ++;
        }else {

            tempBuffer[leftStart + lindex + rindex] = rv;
            rindex ++;
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < end - leftStart + 1; index ++) {

        a[leftStart + index] = tempBuffer[leftStart + index];
    }
}
```

I thought the mergeData function can replace data in the point a each other without the temp buffer, but the logic is too complex and the efficient is not fast, so i add the temp buffer in this function.

Would you have better suggestions if you have willing?